# Reopen test on unmodified question

Tags: discussion, review, review-audits, vote-to-reopen, disputed-review-audits

I got dinged for my disinclination to vote to reopen on https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/1470791.

Now, my policy is simple. If five people voted to close something, I don't second-guess them. If the question has not been edited, I don't vote to reopen it.

I object to being told off in this case.

I don't claim that no one should ever second-guess a close vote, but I don't see why I should have to.

Comment: Wow that is a really low quality question. How the ***fluff*** did that become an audit?!

Comment: Bah, I would have failed that one too. Nothing in it says "reopen-worthy" to me.

Comment: It's not a very good question, but I also don't see why it warrants being closed. I'd probably have opened it in a new tab so that I could downvote the question, which would have "spoiled" the audit, but I've done the same on non-audit questions before. I've failed one or two reopen audits, though, and in both cases I voted to close the question afterwards... in general, the reopen audits seem to be less clear-cut than other queues.

Comment: I just experienced the very same thing. And not the fist time either. The reopen audits should be improved much :(

Answer (score 9):

We suspected that the Reopen Queue audits would be the most difficult – and they are, judging by the failure rates. So, right now, Reopen audit failures don't contribute to automatic review bans, since we're still monitoring it.

That said, *the entire point* of the Reopen Queue is to second-guess close votes.

> Now, my policy is simple. If five people voted to close something, I don't second-guess them.

If that's your policy, then the Reopen Queue probably isn't for you.

Comment: Well, I *thought* that I could participate in the queue by looking for *edited questions* and judging the edits. I can rethink my point of view or I can click 'skip' as needed.

Comment: Even if the question *has* been edited, @Rosinante, you should be asking yourself "should this be closed in its current state" not "did the user put in honest effort". In both the close and re-open queues, strive to evaluate each question on its merits - not on the actions of others.

Comment: @Shog9 "Judging the edits" was meant to imply "Judging the net result question from the edits." Sorry to be unclear.

Comment: So just judge the net result in all cases, @Ros. If you don't feel comfortable doing that for a particular topic, skip.

Comment: @Shog9 yes, precisely, point taken.

Comment: For me to consider reopening a question on sites where I moderate it **has** to have been modified, unless it has 3 or 4 reopen votes already. As this stands I'm going to fail a lot of these reviews.

Comment: I violently disagree. An ancient question that was closed by 5 people and got no activity ever since shall not be reopened *now* even if everyone and the pussycat messed up back then. I expect at least one champion to drive the reopen movement and provide a hint why. By editing the text or leave a comment.